# Flash Messages in Partials (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial,
`_flash.html.haml`

```
- flash.each do |type, value|
  .flash{ :class => type.to_s }
    = value
```

Which I'm rendering from a view using

`=render :partial => "flash"`

Which complains that the flash hash is nil/undefined. However, when I do this:

`=render :partial => "flash", :locals => {:flash => flash}`

It works.

Why doesn't the partial have access to the flash message?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In previous versions of Rails (Rails 2), the default local variable would look for an instance variable with the same name as the partial in the parent.

Given your example since the partial is named `_flash` it would automatically pass the instance variable flash as a local to the partial. Thus you would have access to it. This behavior was deprecated in 2.3 and has been removed in Rails 3.0.

This means that you always have to explicitly pass all instance variables as `locals`, even `flash`, just as you wrote in your latter example.

`<%= render :partial => "flash", :locals => {:flash => flash} %>`

This has nothing to do with `flash` per say, `flash` is a instance variable just as any other.

Comment: But `flash` isn't an instance variable in the parent view, it's a method on `ActionView::Base`, which is essentially the same as being a helper method. So why doesn't `flash` in the partial call the same method?

Comment: It's because namespace shadowing. The partial is named flash, therefore it reserves the variable name flash within the partial to delegate to flash ivar in the parent template, regardless of whether flash even exists. As @tothemario answered, naming it something else will stop the namespace shadowing.

Comment: @Cluster, I think you just blew my mind. Sometimes I wonder if Rails "majic" isn't a little too magical for it's own good.

Answer (score 22):

Because your partial is named "_flash", you should have the :object local to specify variable flash inside the partial.

Change your partial name and you will be able to use flash inside, for example:

```
= render "show_flash_names"
```

Comment: I used = render 'layouts/flash_messages'. I like your solution better than explicitly passing locals. (:locals => {:flash => flash} is so verbose -- yuck)

Comment: +1 on this: simply don't name it "flash" and you can access the Rails flash object as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed, that was driving me insane

Answer (score 5):

Every partial is rendered in a context which contains an implicit local variable whose name is that of the partial (excluding the leading underscore). So a `_flash.html.haml` partial will [*always*](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b8dd70083d747535cc35dce176e5afb6ad98177/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb#L263) have a `flash` local which shadows `ActionView::Base#flash`. If you don't pass an argument to the partial (either via `:locals => {:flash => flash}` or `:object => flash`, the value of the local is simply `nil`.

As suggested, you can rename the partial to avoid the name conflict, or use the more verbose calls to `render`.

This is an annoying misfeature of Rails, in my opinion, and [I'd like to see it changed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyonrails-core/JOkzRehKh7M/sHiSiBDAdOkJ).

Comment: This is the most complete answer, supplying the cause and possible workarounds.  I also appreciate his efforts toward removing the "surprise" from this "feature".

Answer (score 4):

This will also achieve your desired result:

`<%= render partial: "flash", object: flash %>`

The `flash` object is being passed to the `admin/shared/flash` partial as `flash`, since the partial is called `flash`. You'll have access to the `flash` object from within the partial as you'd expect it in any regular view.