# Railstutorial: Putting flash messages in partial yields error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org, partials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash Messages in Partials (Rails 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111844/flash-messages-in-partials-rails-3)

I am doing Michael Hartl's Railstutorial and [listing 7.26](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code-layout_flash) adds flash messages to the application layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
.
.
.
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine.

However, I tried to clean up this code by creating a _flash.html.erb in my partial folder...

```
<% flash.each do |key,value| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
  <!-- <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div> -->
<% end %>
```

...and than using...

```
<%= render 'partials/flash' %>
```

...in my application layout all my Rspec tests start failing with the following message for each test:

```
 Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

The key issue seems to be that flash is nil because wrapping my _flash partial in an if statement like this...

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
  <% flash.each do |key,value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
    <!-- <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div> -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

... yields the same error message about NilClass as above and wrapping it in an if statement like this...

```
<% if flash %>
  <% flash.each do |key,value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
    <!-- <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div> -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

... breaks the flash messages from working (because 'if flash' is always false).

I have two related questions:

1. Why/how exactly does using the partials/flash solution change the behavior of a rails app?
2. How to change my partials/flash so it will work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set locals with a hash of params/values to pass to the partial

```
<%= render :partial => "partials/flash", :locals => {:flash => flash} %>
```